# How to pass email address in the format test@test1.com in an update query to the Access DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

I am trying to update the email column in the Access DB as "test@test1.com".
But I am getting this error / exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'test@test1.com'.

My code is as follows.

```
  string em = "test@" + comId + ".com";
  string cmd = "UPDATE tblWebUsers SET Email ="+ em +" WHERE CustRole = 'SuperAdmin'";
  OleDbCommand cmdv3 = new OleDbCommand(cmd, con);
  cmdv3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help???

Comment: put single quotes around string vals "UPDATE tblWebUsers SET Email ='"+ em +"' WHERE CustRole = 'SuperAdmin'";

Comment: also a good idea to use parameters instead of raw sql

Comment: Yes its my bad that i forgt ot use thesingle quotes for emailvariable but i used for the CustRole . @dbugger thanks buddy.  
 Yes I normally use parameters . when i got error I just want to test it in this way. i use Parameters to escape from sqlinjection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email address in the query isn't between quotes, so the db server tries to resolve the email address as an instruction instead of a string.

```
  string em = "test@" + comId + ".com";
  string cmd = "UPDATE tblWebUsers SET Email ='"+ em +"' WHERE CustRole = 'SuperAdmin'";
  OleDbCommand cmdv3 = new OleDbCommand(cmd, con);
  cmdv3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what dbugger said.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is a single mistake from me .
For passing string values inside a query in access db you must enclose it within  a single quotes.  Another better way and the approach to be taken for safe coding is use parameters

```
            string email = "test@test1.com";
            string comp = "test1";
            string cmd = "UPDATE tblCustomerUsers SET Email = ? WHERE  CompanyID = ? AND CustRole = 'SuperAdmin'";
            OleDbCommand cmdv3 = new OleDbCommand(cmd, con);
            cmdv3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", email);
            cmdv3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", comp);
            cmdv3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Thank you for those who answered. I really appreciate your good work.